# Why are functions executed in the order they are defined and not in the order they are called from the int main() in avr-c?

Tags: c, avr, atmega, avr-gcc

I am trying to learn AVR C, and was tinkering with the atmega328p microcontroller. I am using the avr-gcc toolchain on Linux Mint to compile and flash my code to the Arduino board.

So I was trying to blink two LED lights, using function calls. I made two functions - one for blinking LED connected to pin 7 and another for blinking LED connected to pin 13 of my Arduino board.

The functions are working, but while I was tinkering with the code, I noticed a strange behavior. The functions are called and executed in the order they are defined in, outside of the main(); and not in the order they are called in from inside the `int main()`.

This is my code

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void blinkPin13() {
    while(1) {
        DDRB = DDRB | (1 << DDB5);
        PORTB = PORTB | (1 << PORTB5);
        _delay_ms(5000);
        PORTB = PORTB & ~(1 << PORTB5);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}

void blinkPin7() {
    while(1) {
        DDRD = DDRD | (1 << DDD7);
        PORTD = PORTD | (1 << PORTD7);
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTD = PORTD & ~(1 << PORTD7);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
}


int main(void) {    
    blinkPin7();
    blinkPin13();
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the makefile used to compile and flash the code

```
default:
    avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o led.o led.c
    avr-gcc -o led.bin led.o
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom led.bin led.hex
    sudo avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex
```

So, when I flash the above code to my Arduino board, the led connected to pin 13 blinks even though the function `blinkPin7()` is called first. I am noticing that the order of execution of the function always corresponds to the order in which the functions are defined outside of the main(), and not to the order in which they are called from inside the main().

Why is this so?

Comment: The order in which functions are defined has nothing to do with the order they are called. They can be defined anywhere: in the same file, in another module, or in a library. All that matters is that they are declared and defined properly.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes ideally it shouldn't, but I am noticing this behavior when I am running this code on my arduino board.

Comment: There is some other reason, probably the logic that calls them. They can't be defined in the "wrong" order.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, there must be something, but I have tried changing the order in which both functions are defined and the order in which they are called too, what I am noticing is ultimately the order in which they are executed is same as the order in which both the functions are defined, which is strange.

Comment: Given the loop in each function, how do you figure it is even getting to the second call? I see nothing that would break out of the loop.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I have tried changing the order in which I have defined both the function , and the order in which I called them from main. So instead of defining ```blinkPin13()``` first I changed the order and put ```blinkPin7()``` first, and then exchanged the order in which they are called from main - so instead of calling ```blinkPin7()``` first as I am doing in the example code I provided, I called ```blinkPin13()``` first. Now, Ideally pin13 should blink, but led connect to pin 7 is blinking.

Comment: Please show the definition of `DDRD` and `PORTD`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo they are mapping to the correct pins if I am calling them independently, so I don't think the problem has anything to do with incorrect usage of these macros, if that's what you meant.

Comment: No, I was mostly interested in if they were `volatile` or not.

Comment: *the led connected to pin 13 blinks even though the function blinkPin7() is called first*. Perhaps it is due to the way the LEDs are wired, and the default output states. This contradicts your earlier statement.

Comment: You can’t be noticing any order, as the first function called never returns. The situation you describe is impossible. Re-examine your assumptions.

Comment: @user207421 I think some kind of order is possible if `DDRD` and/or `PORTD` (or what they are mapped to) aren't `volatile`. That would mean that the program has UB and then, who knows what happens.

Comment: @user207421 you are right that both of the function never returns, but when I run this code, if I call blinkPin7() first in my main(), I should see led connected to pin 7 blinking, and if I call blinkPin13() first in my main(), I should see led connected to pin 13 blinking. But what I am saying is that the function which is called first(and hence never returns) is the one which is defined first, and not the one in which is called first.

Comment: Neither function will return, and only one of them will ever be called. Their position in the source code is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, only one function will be called, but which function is it which will be called should depend on which is called first. Which is not happening here.

Comment: Is the `main` function actually used in this environment?  Does the linker set things up to run any function of type `void(void)` at startup?

Comment: I don't have experience with Arduino, but perhaps this device needs to be synchronized. It doesn't seem accidental that these functions are infinite loops. Can you add a side effect to your functions, like setting a global variable? I suspect the explanation is simpler than this.

Comment: Try removing the `main` function and see what happens.

Comment: @dbush it runs just like before even after removing main, so I think like you said, it has to do with how main is used this environment. How do I check if the linker set thing up to run the function of type ```void``` at startup, any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. But your Makefile isn't correct.

> ```
> avr-gcc -o led.bin led.o
> ```

It does not pass `-mmcu=atmega328p` in link stage. Without this option, you should get an ld error like this:

```
avr:103 architecture of input file `led.o' is incompatible with avr output
```

Meaning you don't have a target mcu. With the proper linker script, the main() starts from address 0 (reset vector), and everything would work properly. But with the wrong linker script, no startup code and interrupt vector table added, whatever function comes first now will be at address 0 and will start to execute as per what you observed.

Add the target mcu would fix the problem:

```
     avr-gcc -o led.bin led.o -mmcu=atmega328p
```